# Drive letter from device ID on Windows with Python

Tags: python, windows, drive, pyusb, deviceid

I have the device ID of a removable drive. How can I use this to identify the drive letter of the device on windows with Python?

Non python answers may help.

Comment: Do you mean the device instance path that's listed in the driver details in the device manager?

Comment: @eryksun Yes, I do! Specifically the product ID

Comment: I mean this [device ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids) -- not a product ID.

Comment: Device ID will also work